# Macrodroid: I want a repeating alert when battery is less than/over than x%

Tags: battery, charging, macrodroid

I want a repeating alert when battery is less than/over than x%.

I have a pair of alerts (Using MacroDroid) that are triggered by a battery level change. One of less than 35%, and one of more than 85%.

It nicely runs a media sound file to alert me. (Ding!)

I want them to *repeatedly* alert me while they are above/below the limit. Currently it only seems to do it once: at the moment that the percentage level drops or increases past each limit. How could I make it sound every (say 5 minutes) when it is above or below the limits?

<sub>I'm becoming obsessed with battery levels ever since I replaced my battery and I found it to be swollen like a rotten grapefruit! :)</sub>

Edit:
I've found some info that accessing the root (whatever that means) can give you access to the sys folder that can actuate the ability of the phone to either charge or not do so. I have done similar things with windows and the registry and feel confident doing these things with the Win OS in the Registry, but not with Android OS. If I access the sys folder and try to save changes it won't let me.

Comment: You need root access to make those changes. I had that implemented back in Android 6.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the trigger Regular interval only. Do not use with any other Trigger. Setup your action, the media tone that is, and use the constraint battery level. You may have to use a logic constraint here, such as AND constraint in MacroDroid specific category.

Comment: +1, of course!  There seems to be no setting for "Battery Level = to". I modified my macro to show (triggers) "Battery level Change : Any value change" ... (actions) "Play Sound", "Display Notification"... (constraints) "Power Connected", "Power level >= 85%". If my battery is at 100% and my power is connected, there is no change ever, right? Bad! What (oh, what) do I do?

Comment: Fun Fact: if my battery is <=0%, I can't get my phone to do *anything.*

Comment: Battery level constraint is available under Battery/power. It can be set for greater, lesser and equal to a certain value. As I mentioned in the answer, do not use any Trigger other than regular interval. The battery level constraint should be used. // I have not tested the condition for 100%. You can use using logic constraint such as AND, OR, etc.

Comment: So... not totally obvious to me. trying now to make my phone discharge to test things out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
If (battery level [>/<]X%)
-Do/while
--media file
```