# Battery low triggering by ringtones and voice in Android phones

Tags: applications, battery, charging, battery-life

Is it technically feasible to have this feature of Battery low triggering by ringtones and voice to the end user say when battery has reached level of 10% or 5% in android os phone devices?

This feature if feasible is also applicable to ios apple phone devices.

Comment: I have not sees such a feature implemented in the Android OS itself, may be there is a manufacturer which has modified Android in such a way. The only alternative would be to use an app that monitors battery state and plays the sound if a certain level is reached. However because of battery optimizations such an app may not work reliable, as the monitoring code is only executed infrequently and if the battery usage is high automatisch shutdown because of low battery may come first before the notification had a chance to trigger and play the sound.

Comment: Related: [Macrodroid: I want a repeating alert when battery is less than/over than x%](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/206369/44325). I think there's another similar question answered with a 3rd-party app, but I couldn't find it now.

Comment: Thanks Robert and Andrew. Can we call this feature as a battery low level alarm trigger in android os and apple ios phones? There could be technical challenges but this can be achieved?